# MS-Access sub-report header and footer conditional and specified

Tags: ms-access

I have a report containing an embedded sub-report. In the print version of the report, the sub-report is usually short enough that it doesn't carry over to the second page and is fine as-is. However, when the sub-report carries over to a second page, I would like it to show a footer on the first page only (that reads "continued on next page"), and an additional header on subsequent pages (that reads "continued from previous page"). I have worked out how to make the sub-report's existing page header show in the main report and repeat on subsequent pages, but I can't seem to create the additional, conditional header and footer to appear when the sub-report's page count is greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the main report's Page Header property to "Not with Rpt Hdr".
2. Set the main report's Page Footer property to "Not with Rpt Ftr".
3. Put the "Continued From Previous Page" in the report's Page Header section.
4. Put the "Continued On Next Page" in the report's Page Footer section.

Now, the "Continued From Previous Page" will show on all but the first page and the "Continued On Next Page" will show on the footer of any page with a subsequent page (i.e. all but the last page).

**ALTERNATIVE**

1. Add a Textbox to the page header section.
2. Set the ControlSource of the Textbox to:

   `=iif([Page]>1, "Continued from previous page", "")`
3. Add a Textbox to the page footer section.
4. Set the ControlSource of the Textbox to:

   `=iif([Page]<[Pages], "Continued on next page", "")`

Comment: Thank you, andrew, for your quick response. I was not familiar with those properties, so that will indeed come in helpful. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in this particular case. Reason being, both my main report and sub report already have Page Headers, as they both must repeat, but no Report Headers. So, I need an additional page header. I tried creating group headers with Expression =0 but couldn't work out how to set the properties of those. I tried using an On Format event to change the visibility properties but that didn't work, either...

Comment: The alternative is to make use of the report's `Me.Page` and `Me.Pages` properties from within the PageHeaderSection_OnFormat event. Page is the current page number and Pages is the total. Then use logic in the OnFormat event to determine whether the label (which contains the text "Continued from previous page") should be visible. Or is that what you already tried too? Or, you could put the "continued" text in a textbox and set its ControlSource to something like: `=iif([Page]>1, "Continued from previous page", "")`. That would make it only show the message on pages greater than 1.